# foundation new command fails, saying npm Node modules not installed

Tags: npm, zurb-foundation

I'm pretty new to basically everything, my apologies. Following the instructions on https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html, i have installed the Foundation CLI globally using NPM.

Here are my versions of everything:

- NodeJS: 10.0.0
- npm: 6.0.0
- Foundation CLI: 2.2.5

Running `foundation new`, I select a website project, enter its name, and choose the basic template.

The command grinds away, but eventually comes up with:

```
There were some problems during the installation.

 ✓ New project folder created.
 ✗ Node modules not installed. Try running npm install manually.
 ✓ Bower components installed.
```

Preceding this output, there's some stuff that looks like its relevant:

```
make: Entering directory '/home/testproject/testproject/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
  g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.3.6"' -I/home/testproject/.node-gyp/10.0.0/include/node -I/home/testproject/.node-gyp/10.0.0/src -I/home/testproject/.node-gyp/10.0.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/testproject/.node-gyp/10.0.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++1y -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
src/libsass.target.mk:139: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o] Error 4
make: Leaving directory '/home/testproject/testproject/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/testproject/testproject/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:225:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1055-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/testproject/testproject/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/testproject/testproject/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
```

I follow the instructions to try running `npm install` manually within the project directory. This produces a lot of output that bursts my terminal's history buffer. But everything ends with:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/testproject/testproject/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:225:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1055-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/testproject/testproject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/testproject/testproject/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/testproject/.npm/_logs/2018-05-04T01_51_12_745Z-debug.log
```

So it looks like the same issue is occuring. The log file mentioned on the last line is 10459 lines long, so I have put it on gist.github.com: https://gist.github.com/MadEmperorYuri/b128b3cd62fc77daa25c1a9dcd5c743b

I am unsure what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can see in here https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues/11755

use command
npx -p node@10 foundation new --framework emails

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Foundation uses gulp-sass@2.1.0 by default, which depends on node-sass@3.0.0. Npm resolves this dependency as node-sass@3.13.1, which is not compatible with Node v8 and higher.

You have to use latest version of gulp-sass. It can be simply done by these steps:

- delete `node_modules/` folder
- delete `package-lock.json` file
- delete `"gulp-sass": "^2.1.0"` in `package.json`
- run `npm i gulp-sass --save-dev`